# Side-By-Side Gifs That Expand When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

First off, I am new to coding. I am trying to put two gifs side by side that when clicked on expand into a pop up window and the videos are enlarged.  I have succeeded in getting the images side by side. The first gif expands when clicked on and acts how I want it to. But the second gif does not. I believe it has to do with the 's both being the same, but I am not sure how to go about using a class or multiple ids to make the modal work correctly. Some help would be much appreciated! Attached is my code.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/*Image Loops*/

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 800px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img id="myImg" src="image.gif" alt="img" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img id="myImg" src="image2.gif" alt="image2" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><br>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique in the page so the browser can only recognize the first one of elements having same `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this part here :

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
```

is getting only first element with this ID. ID should be unique.

The solution to this would be using a class instead but there's a problem with that approach. The problem is when you get elements by Classname it returns HTML collection to which you can't **bind an event** without looping it which would make things complicated.
So the best solution to this instead of binding an event use `onClick` as an attribute and call a function.


**Solution**

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
 function modalOpen(src,alt){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = src;
    captionText.innerHTML = alt;
 }

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
    .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    .caption{
    text-align:center
    }
    /*Image Loops*/
    
    #myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
    
    }
    
    #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
    
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    
    /* Modal Content (image) */
    .modal-content {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 1600px;
        height: 800px;
    }
    
    /* Caption of Modal Image */
    #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Add Animation */
    .modal-content, #caption {    
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
        to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform:scale(0)} 
        to {transform:scale(1)}
    }
    
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <img id="myImg" onclick="modalOpen(this.src,this.alt)" src="http://via.placeholder.com/128x128" alt="img" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><p class="caption">img</p><br>
</div>
    <div class="column">
    <img id="myImg" onclick="modalOpen(this.src,this.alt)" src="http://via.placeholder.com/129x129" alt="image2" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><p class="caption">image2</p><br>
</div>
</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. That got both images to respond how I want, but now the caption when the image is enlarged says "undefined". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Edited my solution. Pass alt with src as well

Comment: Thank you that worked! One final question (promise this is the last one)...is there a way to put a caption on the images when they are just on the page and haven't been clicked on? If that makes sense. I tried to use a <figcaption>, but that messes up the modal and how it behaves.

Comment: Where do you want to put the caption? on the image or somewhere else. Why don't you use simple div or p?

Comment: I just want to put it below the image.

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Why don't you use it like this

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: If this helped you, you can mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the actual images, but I believe this should work.

```js
// Get the modal
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
const captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 if (event.target.matches('img')) {
  loadModalImage(event.target);
 }
}, false);

const loadModalImage = (target) => {
 modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = target.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = target.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/*Image Loops*/

.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 800px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="img" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="image2" text-align="center" style="width:100%"><br>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not downvoting but the above answer doesn't contribute to the question. You completely transformed the code ignoring that he has written in his question 'First off, I am new to coding'. You didn't explain whats wrong either